# Unable to install the app in iPhone for testing. Because of UDID issue

Tags: ios, iphone, udid

When I try to added the device UDID In the developer account loader has come for 30 min and got hang. When I logged in back to developer account device was added in the list.

I have added the device to Provisioning Profiles but unable to install the app in iPhone. Please help me to resolve the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure that you used correct mobile provisioning profile? Maybe you added UDID in portal but used old provision for the new build?

To check it you can:

1. unzip .ipa-file you are trying to install
2. After this open package with content of app
3. Open file embeded.mobileprovision
4. Check if UDID of your device is listed inside this file (using text search)

If it is missed then you should rebuild your app using new provision profile from Developer Portal.

Comment: Vanger, I am sure that I have used updated provisioning profile and added device as well.. but still getting the error only in one device..

Comment: Also I did unzip the ipa file and checked for the UDID and I found the udid in the list.

Comment: UDID shared by client was wrong. now i have added the right UDID and it is working fine. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Did you make you iPhone for developing in Device Organiser? Anyway you should check in your Developer Account whats wrong. Check certificates etc.

Comment: I have selected right certificate and used updated provisioning profile.. but still getting error only in one iPhone...

Comment: Did you import certificates on your Mac KeyChain? Anyway it's hard to suggest you something from here